# Need help to understand an equation of getting a length of vector from vector operations?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

Can somebody explain what the bold italic sentence means and what's the relationship between $\vec{w}$ and $\delta$?

[image]

This value of delta is ½ the margin for our decision boundary.  In Euclidean geometry, the shortest distance from a point to a hyperplane is one that is orthogonal to the hyperplane (perpendicular to the line in 2 dimensions). In the plot, delta equals the difference between vector A and vector B.  ***We know that delta is in the opposite direction of our normal vector (marked in red)***.  We can use this fact and first compute the pure direction of our normal vector by dividing it by its norm and then multiply it by delta to gives us a vector of length delta and pointing in the direction of the norm.  We then subtract this value from A to arrive at point B on our hyperplane.

$B=A-\delta\dfrac{\vec{w}}{||\vec{w}||}$

Comment: Is the line _regression line_ for *+* and *-* points?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the topic for my question. Yes it is.it is from Support Vector Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $\delta$ is being measured from $A$ to $B$, so all that the highlighted sentence is saying is that the vector $B-A$ points in the opposite direction from $\vec w$, which is why you subtract instead of adding in the formula at the end.